# Linking of rivers in India

Tags: india, geopolitics

While some parts of the country is experiencing floods, several other parts are experiencing drought like situation. 
What are the problems and issues expected if rivers are linked across India apart from economical and geopolitical impact.

Comment: If geopolitical and economic impacts are excluded, then this question would appear to be about engineering, or Earth Science, rather than politics.

Comment: What James K said. Questions on this website must be about governments, policies and political processes. Just because a topic is *relevant* for political decision making doesn't make it on-topic here. The litmus test is "would a political scientist be more qualified to answer this than any other scientist?". In this case the answer is no. It's a question for an environmental engineer, meteorologist, geologist or whatever other scientific discipline can tell us what happens when you redirect a river.

Comment: how to think philipp this question is not related to politics, now in india all politicians have a role for this river interlinking, it is also very important for 80% of farmers in india, philipp do not know about india? please admin will take steps to open this question.

Answer (score 2):

There are flood conditions in most parts of India at the moment, so linking the rivers across the country is a very good idea, and it is also feasible. It was first initiated by former prime minister Shri Atal Bihari Vajpayee, but he could not complete it due to a change in government. Now Nitin Gadkari has re-started the project and it is [continuing apace.](http://wrmin.nic.in/forms/list.aspx?lid=1279)

There is no hurdle but a clear understanding, proper vision and effective implementation. But there is one issue which is [inter-state water disputes between the states of India](https://qz.com/504127/why-indias-168-billion-river-linking-project-is-a-disaster-in-waiting/)